# How do I make my HTML text change dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a mini app project. I made an earlier one where I can change the background color with a button click. I am trying to modify it to get the text to change as the colors are changing and I have been so unsuccessful. I would really appreciate getting put through this. I just started teaching myself to code a month and a half ago. I would like the text to change dynamically with the text in the variable of colors as that corresponds to the colors that change

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const body = document.querySelector('#body-background');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'white'];

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var colorIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * colors.length);
  body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
})
```

```html
<body id="body-background">
  <div>
    <h1 class="hex-codes">#FFC0CB</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">CLICK ME!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how do you want to change your text? narrower representation?

Comment: I want the text to relect the color being changed. Those colors in the array. For instance if the background color changes to red, the text changes to red to match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way how you can randomly create a **hex color** and assign an `id` with `document.getElementById`:

```js
function hexCode() {
    // storing all letter and digit combinations 
    // for html color code 
    var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
  
    // html color code starts with # 
    var color = '#'; 
  
    // generating 6 times as HTML color code consist 
    // of 6 letter or digits 
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
       color += letters[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16))]; 
       
       
    document.getElementById("hex-codes").innerHTML = color;
    document.getElementById("hex-codes").style.color = color;
}

const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const body = document.querySelector('#body-background');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'white'];

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var colorIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * colors.length);
  body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
})
```

```html
<body id="body-background">
  <div>
    <h1 id="hex-codes">#000000</h1>
    <h2 id="hexcode"></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">Change Background Color!</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" onclick="hexCode()">Change Text Color!</button>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
```

I hope you imagined it like this!

Comment: This is amazing. I never imagined it like this. Thanks for opening my mind to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: and which solution did you take?

Comment: I take the one before but I stored up this code for a separate project. I just started learning to code a month and a half ago so there is a lot I do not know.

Comment: okay nice. Then please **confirm** this question or make a **upvote** to this, so other user see that this answer was helpful and useful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's quite the same, and you can do it in various ways and I'm recommending you to learn [how to use css with javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

So when you want to change background color you use `background-color` and when you want to change text color you use `color` and `innerText`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const text = document.querySelector('#dynamic-text');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'white'];

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var colorIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * colors.length);
  text.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
  text.innerText = colors[colorIndex];
})
```

```html
<body id="body-background">
  <div>
    <h1 id="dynamic-text">Dynamic Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">CLICK ME!</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: This changes the colors of the text with respect to the colors. I would like th text itself to change with respect to the colors. For instance, the color red should display text red.